# How to only show the functions that are defined in the class for Dokka Kotlin Kdoc?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-dokka, kdoc

**Question**
How to only show the functions that are defined in the class?

**Screenshots**

[image: k_2021-03-16_18-39-53]

**Installation**

- Operating system: Windows
- Build tool: Gradle v6.8.2
- Dokka version: 1.4.20

**Additional context**
Please specify in my Android build.gradle file, what configuration should I add with examples. Having so many hundreds of functions that I did not defined makes the doc almost unuseable.

The screenshot shown above is generated for the Class. As you can see, only `nice` function and `onCreate` doc should have been generated:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        nice("PIZZA")
    }

    /**
     * Deserve it pizza nice
     */
    fun nice(poi: String){
        Log.d("Nice", "nice: FUN $poi ")
    }
}
```

Here is what I tried:

```
android {

    dokkaHtml.configure {
        dokkaSourceSets {
            named("main") {
                noAndroidSdkLink.set(false)
                skipEmptyPackages.set(true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```